# Solving time dependent schrodinger equation using RK4

Tags: numerical-methods, quantum-mechanics, runge-kutta-methods

Assuming $\hbar = 1$, $m = 1$ and $V$ only depends on $x$, the Schrodinger equations becomes:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}(x,t) 
= \frac{i}
{2}(\nabla^2 + V(x))\Psi(x,t)
\end{equation}
Given $x_0$, define $f(t) = \Psi(x_0,t)$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t) = F(t,f(t)) 
\end{equation}
using aproximation for $\nabla^2$:
\begin{equation}
F(t,f)=\frac{i}{2} 
        \left( \frac{\Psi(x_0+h_x,t)-2\Psi(x_0,t)+\Psi(x_0-h_x,t)}{h_x^2}-
        V(x_0)f \right)
\end{equation}
I want to find $f_n \approx \psi(x_0,t_0+nh_t) = \psi(x_0,t_n)$, given $f_0 = \psi(x_0,t_0)$, using $RK4$ define:
\begin{align*}
     k_1 &= F(t_n,f_n) \\
     k_2 &= F(t_n+\frac{h_t}{2},f_n+\frac{h_t}{2}k_1) \\
     k_3 &= F(t_n+\frac{h_t}{2},f_n+\frac{h_t}{2}k_2) \\
     k_4 &= F(t_n+h_t,f_n + h_tk_3)
\end{align*}
then:
\begin{equation}
f_{n+1} = f_n + \frac{h_t}{6}(k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4) 
\end{equation}
The problem is, to find let's say $k_4$ y need to know $\Psi(x_0,t_n+h_t) = f_{n+1}$, how can I apply $RK4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up notations. The RK4 method is explicit. You use $f_n+h_tk_3$ as approximation of the array $Ψ(x_j,t_n+h_t)$, $j=0,...,M$, where $x_j=x_0+jh_x$.

Also, your use of $x_0$ is obfuscating the complexity of the problem. You compute the approximations of $Ψ(x_j,t_n+h_t)$ where $x_j=x_0+jh_x$ all simultaneously, there is no way around this (esp. if $V$ is not constant, as then even the Fourier coefficients are coupled). Thus
$$
F_j(t_n,f_n)=\frac{i}{2} 
        \left( \frac{f_{n,j+1}-2f_{n,j}+f_{n,j-1}}{h_x^2}-
        V(x_j)f_j \right).
$$
You might have to replace $V(x_j)f_j$ with some local average to fit the approximation model, for instance when starting from finite elements or some other Galerkin scheme.